# how to make compatibility between two parties working on different jdk versions

Tags: java, java-6, jdk1.4, forward-compatibility

My project is build in 1.4.2 JDK.
Now it is going to interact with a third party jar, build in JDK 1.6

I am getting compatibility problem while using client classes.
Is it possible to resolve it without upgrading my JDK to 1.6 or rebuilding third party jar in 1.4.2

Comment: The second option will probably fail, since the third-party jar probably uses Java 1.6 functions.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by the term "interact"? Run directly on JDK 1.4 or interact with your project through the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a class compiled with JDK 1.6 on previous JDK 1.4 because you will got an `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` exception. This is due to Java is not forward compatible, it is just backward compatible (see [specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)).

In order to verify it I have installed JDK 1.4.2.19 and JDK 1.6.0.23 and wrote a sample application:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Built it with JDK 1.6.0.23:

```
 ../1.6.0.23/bin/javac HelloWorld.java
```

And run it with JDK 1.4.2.19:

```
../1.4.2.19/bin/java HelloWorld
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld
(Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        ...
```

**Solution**: You may try to rebuild your third party application with JDK 1.4 if it doesn't call methods introduced in 1.6 (and 1.5).